# req.isAuthenticated() always return false and req.session.passport is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I know that there are some questions like this already, but i already tried every single response and nothing works, i don't know what the heck to add to app.js to make it work and store the sessions.

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

const connectDB = require("./db/connect");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/v1/users", usersRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}....`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const notFound = require("./middleware/notFound");
app.use(notFound);

start();
```

My passport-config looks like this:

```
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("../models/user");

const initialize = (passport) => {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: "That email is not registered",
      });
    }
    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user, { message: "User logged in" });
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e);
    }
  };
  passport.use(new localStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticateUser));
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = initialize;
```

And my users router looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");

const initializePassport = require("../config/passport-config");
initializePassport(passport);

const { postRegister } = require("../controllers/register");
router.route("/register").post(postRegister);

router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: info.message });
    }
    console.log(req.session.passport);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm making a middleware to authorize or to not authorize the call to another endpoint based on if it is authenticated or if it isn't.

Here is how that middleware looks:

```
const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  console.log(req.session.passport);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  }
  next();
};

module.exports = checkAuthenticated;
```

```
const checkNotAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    res
      .status(401)
      .json({ msg: "Not allowed to this path without credentials" });
  }
};

module.exports = checkNotAuthenticated;
```

req.session.passport is undefined, isAuthenticated() is always false, i don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug in the deserializer function:

It will work by changing your deserializer callback argument from user to id as shown below.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  done(err, user);
});
```

That was a very obvious bug to me, to be sure you are not missing any other thing, check the lengthy answer I gave to this on another thread a few minutes ago here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/914#issuecomment-1241921637

Good luck.